# How do i destroy session of a particular user using Id?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

How to destroy the session of a particular user using his/her `user_id` ?

I have an events like when admin assign role to a normal user then, if the normal user is logged in, I have to destroy the session of the normal user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: it depends what store do you use for sessions

Comment: I'm using express-session and want to destroy the remotely user session

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The session of the logged in user has an id that you can save after successful login: `req.session.id`.  Then you can retrieve that user's session from the memory store at any time and destroy it using:

```
sessionStore = express.session.MemoryStore();
sessionStore.get(id, function(err, sess) {
  sess.destroy (function (err) {

  });
});
```